# I want to change firebase database of existing application

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application based on firebase database, now I want to change the database of this existing project. Is it possible? If yes, then how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You have got 2 options:

1. Keep the same project, but change your database: simply import your new Database (JSON file) from the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).
2. Create another project, download the new configuration file and add it to your application. You'll get a brand new database with the new project.

Comment: sir actually i am new for android technology, i am not getting properly that how can be import and use it with my project. Can you please explain more or provide a suitable link ???

Comment: This is not really related to Android. Log into the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data) and open the Database section. You'll see your database. On the top right corner, you'll see 3 dots. Click it and you'll see an import option